# How to distinguish between relative path and domain in location header of redirect

Tags: http

According to [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.1) a URI reference may not have a leading slash and form a relative path:

```
A relative reference that begins with two
 slash characters is termed a network-path 
reference; such references are rarely
 used. A relative reference that begins 
with a single slash character is termed an
 absolute-path reference. A relative 
reference that does not begin with a slash 
character is termed a relative-path 
reference.
```

Also, according to [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) the `location` header may contain a URI reference:

```
The field value consists of a single URI-
reference. 
 When it has the form of a relative 
reference ([RFC3986], Section 4.2),
 the final value is computed by resolving 
it against the effective request URI
   ([RFC3986], Section 5).
```

How can I distinguish between a redirect to a relative URL and a new URL?

I.e., I am at `http://foo.bar` and receive a 3XX with `location = baz.htm`.
How do I know whether this is a relative path or a new domain?

Do I continue at `http://too.bar/baz.htm` or at `http://baz.htm`?

Comment: baz.htm is a relative reference. See linked specs.

Comment: But how do you know? How can you tell? What if it was `baz.x`? Is there a pre defined list of postfix denoting a file instead of an URL? The specs do not mention anything like this.

Comment: "baz.x" is a relative reference. Even "example.com" is. Just read the spec.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be indeed found further up in RFC3986:

```
If the URI-reference's prefix does not match
 the syntax of a scheme followed by its colon
 separator, then the URI-reference is a relative reference.
```